# How to use metadata API in lightning web component

Tags: lightning-web-components, metadata-api

I am pretty new to metadata API, I wonder how can I use metadata API to push some JSON metadata just like in jsForce(I successfully use jsForce in this way below in my local web app, but I am not sure how to use it in Lightnint web component):

[image]

I have a Lightning web component here, and I want to push the same metadata above here, but I do not know how to use similar metadata API(I do not have to use jsForce, any API does same thing will be fine):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Calling metadata API from LWC is not trivial as mentioned in [Salesforce doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/apex_api_calls.htm)

> By security policy, sessions created by Lightning components aren’t
>   enabled for API access. This prevents even your Apex code from making
>   API calls to Salesforce. Using a named credential for specific API
>   calls allows you to carefully and selectively bypass this security
>   restriction.
>
> The restrictions on API-enabled sessions aren’t accidental. Carefully
>   review any code that uses a named credential to ensure you’re not
>   creating a vulnerability.

As a workaround, I have used a VF page to generate a valid session Id which has API access.

I'm also using [apex-mdapi open-source library](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) to call metadata API

Sample code to create a Custom object using the Metadata API:

**VF Page to generate API access enabled session Id(SessionId.page)**

```
<apex:page>
    Start_Of_Session_Id{!$Api.Session_ID}End_Of_Session_Id
</apex:page>
```

**LWC Component**

```
<template>
    <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Create Object" title="Primary action" onclick={createObjectInApex} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
</template>

import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import createObject from '@salesforce/apex/CreateObjectCtrl.execute';

export default class CreateObject extends LightningElement {
    createObjectInApex() {
        createObject()
        .then(() => {
            console.log("Metadata api called successfully");
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }
}
```

**Apex Controller**

```
public with sharing class CreateObjectCtrl {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void execute() {
        MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService();     
        MetadataService.CustomObject customObject = new MetadataService.CustomObject();
        customObject.fullName = 'Test__c';
        customObject.label = 'Test';
        customObject.pluralLabel = 'Tests';
        customObject.nameField = new MetadataService.CustomField();
        customObject.nameField.type_x = 'Text';
        customObject.nameField.label = 'Test Record';
        customObject.deploymentStatus = 'Deployed';
        customObject.sharingModel = 'ReadWrite';

        service.createMetadata(new MetadataService.Metadata[] { customObject });        
    }


    private static MetadataService.MetadataPort createService() { 
        MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
        service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
        //NOTE: in context of LWC UserInfo.getSessionId() has not API enabled access
        service.SessionHeader.sessionId = apiEnabledSessionId(); 
        return service;     
    }


    private static String apiEnabledSessionId(){
        PageReference sessionPage = Page.SessionId;
        String vfContent = sessionPage.getContent().toString();
        Integer startIndex = vfContent.indexOf('Start_Of_Session_Id') + 'Start_Of_Session_Id'.length();
        Integer endIndex = vfContent.indexOf('End_Of_Session_Id');

        return vfContent.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, the app I create is used on lightning platform, so when the user use it, he already logged in, is there a way I can use that session to authorize a metadata API call?

Comment: No, As mentioned in the linked salesforce doc. sessions created by Lightning components aren’t enabled for API access. To work with Metadata API you should either call apex from VF page context or use the Session Id of a VF page

Comment: thanks. I use App manager created the lightning app, does that create a VF page? I am pretty new to this, now sure if I am in the right track.

Comment: you will have to create VF page from the developer console(Sample Code is available in my answer). Check this doc to get started with VF page https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_hello_world.htm

Comment: Thanks, could you show me how to use that lightning web component in the visualforce page? I follow some dev guide which said I need an aura app to do that, I wonder if it is possible to directly use lightning web component in VisualForce

Comment: I had a talk with the Security Review Team about this last year in an office hours. 
They were adamant exposing a API enabled sessionId to the client in Lightning  is a No-Go.