# Calling REST APIs from Lightning

Tags: rest-api, oauth2, tooling-api, namedcredentials

We are currently working on an app where we are calling the *Tooling API* from our Lightning component

Since `UserInfo.getSessionId()` is not valid in Lightning context, to make the call we are using VF page to capture session Id. We are worried if this approach will get rejected during Security Review.

We even tried *oAuth 2.0* with *Named Credential* but not sure if there is a way to dynamically update *Callback URL* for connected App for different orgs.

What's the right approach for calling Tooling API from Lightning such that it passes the Security Review?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use metadata API in lightning web component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/306365/how-to-use-metadata-api-in-lightning-web-component)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have used the same. Using VF page to capture the session but it's seems like workaround. I am worried if it will stop working after some releases.

Comment: Using oAuth 2.0 with Named Credential looks good but i am unable to get a way to update callback URL for Connected app with the Auth provider callback URL automatically. Please let me know if you have any idea on this.

Answer (score 1):

For all security questions (like whether session Id got using vf merge tag) open an office hour with the Salesforce Security Review team. You can find more info on [office hours](https://security.secure.force.com/sourcescanner/). You need your partner community credentials for this.

Because of security reasons, there is no way to update the callback URLs dynamically for the connected app without using a Metadata API.

It is recommended that you provide manual post-install instructions for salesforce administrators to set this up as a part of app configuration and instructions.

Comment: Thanks Mohit. We will schedule Office hour to get more insight on that.

Comment: @KESHAV did you ever get an answer?